# Delete all words starting with a certain pattern in sed

Tags: regex, sed, makefile

I have an input like that:

```
A.x: ksvbskv sdbvfv /a/b/c \
     vvsvr /a/b /a/b/m/d \
     hmnghmgh
```

I need a `sed` command pattern which deletes all words starts with `/a/b` and the output will be:

```
A.x: ksvbskv sdbvfv \
     vvsvr \
     hmnghmgh
```

I have used this for a Makefile target. So I can trim some specific values.

Comment: @Taner it might be worth including some examples of sed commands you have tried and the output you got from those, as people will probably be able to modify your previous attempts faster than they can come up with ideas from scratch.

Comment: @robjohncox I have no sed command example (for reason not knowing sed well). I needed this for a code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ sed 's%/\ba/b[^ ]*%%g' file
A.x: ksvbskv sdbvfv  \
     vvsvr   \
     hmnghmgh
```

Explanation:

```
s      # Substitute 
%      # Delimiter
\b     # Word boundary
a/b    # Literal string
[^ ]*  # Zero or more characters that are not a space
%      # Delimiter
%      # Delimiter
g      # Global substitution
```

Comment: Thank you both your answer and explanation, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...

```
$ sed 's%/\[a-b][^ ]*%%g' file
```